# how to use typescript keyof in function arguments with enum values?

Tags: typescript, enums

i'm curious that usage of enum with keyof keyword.
here is the sample code without enum.

```js
const map = new Map<string, string>();

interface ShopStoreProps {
    google: string;
    apple: string,
    galaxy: string
}

const setValue = <T extends keyof ShopStoreProps>(shopProps: T, value: string) => {
    return map.set(shopProps, value);
}

setValue('google', 'test1'); // ok
setValue('appleee', 'test2'); // error
```

but I want to use only enum not the upper interface like this.
of course I know that the below `setValue function` is wrong grammatically.
thank you for reading this question. :)

```js
const map = new Map<string, string>();

enum ShopStoreEnum {
    GOOGLE = 'google',
    APPLE = 'apple',
    GALAXY = 'galaxy',
}

const setValue = <T extends keyof ShopStoreEnum>(shopProps: T, value: string) => {
    return map.set(shopProps.name, value);
}

setValue(ShopStoreEnum.GOOGLE, 'test1'); // to be
```

Comment: Does `setValue` have to be generic on type `shopProps` ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `extends keyof` simply use `extends`.

```
const setValue = <T extends ShopStoreEnum>(shopProps: T, value: string) => {
    return map.set(shopProps, value);
}
```

One might ask, why make it generic at all? You would achieve the same result with this:

```
const setValue = (shopProps: ShopStoreEnum, value: string) => {
    return map.set(shopProps, value);
}
```

Comment: I guess I thought it was too hard. thank you